# Security risks of remote images

Tags: php, security, remote-access

On one of my websites, users pay for file storage, so naturally, they are going to want to offload as many of their resources onto remote servers as they can afford, especially because I limit file types to prevent dangerous files on my server.

In most cases, this will not be a problem as it is not dangerous for my server to give them the URL so that their machine can get it, but there is one case when this can be a problem:

I have one script on my website that will access all of the entries in my database and return the URL of the image associated with that entry for public viewing. This still does not pose a threat to my server, but the issue is liability. For all other cases, the users are responsible for what they share with their team, but when it is public, this can theoretically be a problem.

What, if any, are the risks of displaying user-provided remote images on my website and how can I prevent liability (other than just saying that the users are responsible for the content they upload in my terms of service)?

Answer (score 1):

**Liability** is, by definition, a legal issue, not a technical one. We cannot give you advice on the legal aspects of this question.

From the technical standpoint, though, there are some issues you'll want to consider. For instance, the servers hosting these images will obviously receive the IP address of users viewing the images. Whether that matters to you will depend on the nature of your web site.

Another issue to consider is that the URL of pages on your web site may be passed to the servers hosting images (i.e, in the `Referrer` HTTP header). If your application contains pages which take sensitive data as URL parameters, and those pages display user-specified images, that data will be exposed.

Finally, it's possible for a malicious (or, at least, clever) user to specify an image that is actually a script which will return different data depending on some variables. (Or, even simpler: they may replace one file with another after inserting it.) Depending on what your web site is doing, this may cause trouble. For instance, if your web site had limits on the size of images, a user could insert an acceptably sized image, then replace the file with a larger one afterwards.